# How do I use the key, in a condition in Cacheable annotation

Tags: java, spring, ehcache, spring-cache

I'm caching the results of a function using the @cacheable annotation.
I have 3 different caches and the key for each one is the user id of the currently logged in user concatenated with an argument in the method .
On a certain event I want to evict all the cache entries which have the key that starts with that particular user id.
For example :

```
@Cacheable(value = "testCache1", key = "'abcdef'")
```

I want the cache evict annotation to be something like :

```
@CacheEvict(value = "getSimilarVendors", condition = "key.startsWith('abc')")
```

But when I try to implement this it gives me an error :

```
Property or field 'key' cannot be found on object of type'org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheExpressionRootObject' - maybe not      public?
```

What is the correct way to implement this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

All of the Spring Cache annotations (i.e. `@Cacheable`, `@CacheEvict`, etc) work on 1 cache entry per operation.  `@CacheEvict` does support clearing the entire cache (with the `allEntries` attribute, however ignores the key in this case), but it is not selective (capable) in clearing a partial set of entries based on a key pattern in a single operation as you have described.

The main reason behind this is the Spring [Cache](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html) interface abstraction itself, where the [evict(key:Object)](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/Cache.html#evict-java.lang.Object-) method takes a single key argument.  But technically, it actually depends on the underlying Cache implementation (e.g. [GemfireCache](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/master/src/main/java/org/springframework/data/gemfire/support/GemfireCache.java#L62-L64)), which would need to support eviction on all entries who's keys match a particular pattern, which is typically, not the case for most caches (e.g. certainly not for GemFire, and not for Google Guava Cache either; see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache.java#L133-L136) and [here](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidate(java.lang.Object)).)

That is not to say you absolutely cannot achieve your goal.  It's just not something supported out-of-the-box.

The interesting thing, minus some technical issues with your approach, is that your condition achieves sort of what you want... a cache eviction only occurs if the key satisfies the condition.  However, you @CacheEvict annotated method is just missing the "key", hence the error.  So, something like the following would satisfy the SpEL in your condition...

```
@CacheEvict(condition = "#key.startsWith('abc')")
public void someMethod(String key) {
  ...
}
```

However, you have to specify the key as an argument in this case.  But, you don't want a specific key, you want a pattern matching several keys.  So, forgo the condition and just use...

```
@CacheEvict
public void someMethod(String keyPattern) {
  ...
}
```

By way of example, using Guava as the caching provider, you would now need to provide a "custom" implementation extending [GuavaCache](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-context-support/src/main/java/org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCache.java).

```
public class CustomGuavaCache extends org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCache {

  protected boolean isMatch(String key, String pattern) {
    ...
  }

  protected boolean isPattern(String key) {
    ...
  }

  @Override
  public void evict(Object key) {
    if (key instanceof String && isPattern(key.toString()))) {
        Map<String, Object> entries = this.cache.asMap();
        Set<String> matchingKeys = new HashSet<>(entries.size());
        for (String actualKey : entries.keySet()) {
          if (isMatch(actualKey, key.toString()) {
            matchingKeys.add(actualKey);
          }
        }
        this.cache.invalidateAll(matchingKeys);
    }
    else {
      this.cache.invalidate(key);
    }
  }
}
```

Now just extend the [GuavaCacheManager](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/cache/guava/GuavaCacheManager.html) to plugin your "custom" `GuavaCache` (`CustomGuavaCache`)...

```
public class CustomGuavaCacheManager extends org.springframework.cache.guava.GuavaCacheManager {

  @Override
  protected Cache createGuavaCache(String name) {
    return new CustomGuavaCache(name, createNativeGuavaCache(name), isAllowNullValues());
  }
}
```

This approach takes advantage of Guava's [Cache's](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html) [invalidateAll(keys:Iterable)](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/cache/Cache.html#invalidateAll(java.lang.Iterable)) method.  And, of course, you could use Java's Regex support to perform the "matching" on the desired keys to be evicted inside the `isMatch(key, pattern)` method.

So, I have not tested this, but this (or something similar) should achieve (almost) what you want (fingers crossed ;-)

Hope this helps!

Cheers,
John