# Spring cache @CacheEvict matches key in a list?

Tags: java, spring, spring-cache

I'm using Spring cache and trying to evict cache by a list of key(id).

```
@CacheEvict(value="cacheName",key=?, condition=? )
public void deleteByIds(List<Integer> ids){...}
```

How can I manage to do that?

Comment: Please have a look into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32460606/how-do-i-use-the-key-in-a-condition-in-cacheable-annotation. it will help you.

Comment: To be specific: a) `foreach` is not an elegant solution; b) I want to evict certain ids of cache under the namespace, so `startWith` spEl cannot suitable for this.

Answer (score 5):

- `@CacheEvict`

> Annotation indicating that a method (or all methods on a class)
>   triggers a cache evict operation.

- The cachaName or value

> Names of the caches in which method invocation results are stored.

- Condition

> Expression used for making the method caching conditional.

- Key

> root.method, root.target, and root.caches for references to the method, target object, and affected cache(s) respectively.

**Solution** for your problem:
Assuming that every object from the List it is cached into, for example cacheName = "entities" and for the key you can use the entity ID (which is the String representation of the Integer value) you should write a second method to evict the cache.

```
public void deleteByIds(List<Intiger> intigers){
 for(Intigier i : intigers){
  deleteEntity(i.toString());
 }
}

@CacheEvict(cacheName = "entities", key="entityId", condition="entityId!=null")
private void deleteEntity(String entityId){
 //processing : for ex delete from the database and also remove from cache
}
```

Comment: This won't work. Calling a method on `this` bypasses spring bean proxies, so @CacheEvict is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

Cache can be cleared by writing code with CacheManager:

```
import org.springframework.cache.Cache;
import org.springframework.cache.CacheManager;
import org.springframework.cache.annotation.CacheEvict;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;

@Service
public class YourService {

    private final CacheManager cacheManager;
    private final YourRepository repository;

    public YourService(CacheManager cacheManager, YourRepository repository) {
        this.cacheManager = cacheManager;
        this.repository = repository;
    }

    public void evictCacheByIds(List<String> ids) {
        Cache cache = cacheManager.getCache("cacheName");
        for (String id : ids) {
            cache.evict(id);
        }
    }

    public void deleteByIdList(List<String> ids) {
        evictCacheByIds(ids);
        repository.deleteByIds(ids);
    }
}
```

You can take a look here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-evict-cache#2-using-cachemanager